# Pointing to an image on Server within XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I can do this within code to load a bitmapimage located on the Server under ClientBin\Images folder:

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "./Images/Default.JPG"));
```

However how do I do this within XAML itself?  Is it even possible?

```
<Image x:Name="NewImage" Source="../Images/Default.JPG"/>
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:-

```
<Image x:Name="NewImage" Source="/Images/Default.JPG"/>
```

Urls in Xaml treat the folder from which the Xap is downloaded (ClientBin usually) as the root, i.e. the path "/" points actually at ClientBin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a relative path in silverlight for an image on the server since the xap file is downloaded to the client, so the application is not actually running on the server. 
you will have to use the full "http://mysite.com/myImage.jpg" path

Comment: ahh makes sense. However this doesn't make it Blendable either. :(

Comment: you could always have the image locally for testing if you need to see it in blend!!

Comment: @Daniel, But then I had to change it back whenever I had a release. If I forget that the xap file becomes huge. is there a good way to automate this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309186/debug-and-release-assembly-refrences-in-xaml i think this is what you need